# How can I manually point to a version of a laguage (python) in my IDE?

Tags: python, pycharm, ide

I am using the IDE Pycharm, but I must have downloaded Python 3.9 outside of it because the version in Pycharm is 3.8 and the version when I run in CMD is 3.9. Is there a way that I can update my Pycharm (or any other IDE for that matter) to point to the 3.9 executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add virtualenv with the desired python,
`virtualenv venv -p python3.9`
Go to menu pycharm==>settings==>python interpeter.
Configure the above virtualenv python to be the interpeter `python venv/bin/python`
[image]

Comment: Thank you much! The fact you're on a Mac threw me, but luckily there's a search feature. Quick question, I try to adjust it and I get an error saying the folder I select isn't empty. Do you know how to get past this if I don't want to change the venv location, but just the python interpreter, or do they have to be in the same location?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a project click on 'Base interpreter' and select your desired version of python from the dropdown and then press create